# In Rails 5, how to render the output of a query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to render the output of a query in my views. I am running Rails verion 5.4.2.1

```
@users = User.with_attached_avatar.where("id not in (:list)", list: xyz)
```

The view code is

```
<ul>
<%= @users %>
</ul>
```

The view code will work, for example, when the controller sends `@users = @team.members` (assuming member is a user) and there is a **_user.html.erb** partial defined. So there is no problem when I use this technique to render a list of association objects.

While the query itself is successful (I checked), the view only prints out the string representation of the returned relations object `#<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007f9468025478>`, not the list.

I can see that the query returns an `ActiveRecord_Relation` object but an association like `@user.messages` would return a `ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy`.

How do I **render the array as a list, like you can do with associations, and partials?**

Comment: do `@users.inspect` to view the response. do `@users.map(&:attributes)` if there are any error in query it will show there

Comment: Do you want to see the object or the array printed? Or do you want to see the query string?

Comment: @Vishal. The query works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
<%= render partial: "user", collection: @users, as: :user %>
```

```
//_user.html.erb
<li>User info: <%= user.name %></li>
```